# mxGraph: Click event from external button

Tags: javascript, mxgraph

Let's say, I have the following html document:

```
  <div id="container" class="container">
       // here comes the mxGraph
  </div>
  <div class="button-container">
    <button id="myButton" type="button" name="button" onclick="myFunction()">Save</button>
  </div>
</body>
```

Is there a way to catch the click-event of myButton in mxGraph?

Comment: What do you mean by catching IN mxGraph? Event is passed as the first argument to the handler function. Could you please describe what you want to achieve?

Comment: I'd like to trigger an xml-save function (mxUtils) with the button.

Comment: Can you just write necessary code in the myFunction?

Comment: That's what I try to do. But the function has to be in the javascript-scope of mxGraph. To concrete my question: Is  mxGraph able to catch events from outside its scope (in this case: from a button that is not insite the mxGraph-div)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can catch event outside the mxgraph-div.

Do the following inside the jquery $(document).ready function:

1. Declare the graph has a global variable.
2. Create a function to load the graph inside the mx-graph div
3. Create the function for the external button click event.
4. Bind the function click event to the Step 3 Created function
5. Call the Step 2 function to load the mx-graph inside the div.
6. In the Step 3 function, you can access the graph object to trigger an xml save

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<ol class="breadcrumb">
<button id='genxml' class="btn  btn-outline-success btn-sm m-2" onclick="this.blur();">
    <span class="fas fa-fw fa-folder"></span> Download XML
</button>
</ol>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
      <div id="graphContainer" class="col-md-12"   style="float:left;position:absolute;overflow:scroll;width:80%;height:80vh;cursor:default;outline:1px solid red">
    </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function(){
     var graph;
     
     function downloadXML(){
    // access the Graph object here to save the mxUtils
         // Block of Code to get the mxGraph mxUtil in the function   
       // var node = encoder.encode(graph.getModel());
      //  mxUtils.popup(mxUtils.getPrettyXml(node), true);
     }
     
     function main(container){
        // Block of Code to load a mxGraph in the Container        
         /* graph = new mxGraph(container);
          graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
            var v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, 'r', req,req_grp_geo.x+30, req_grp_geo.y+40, 160, 40,'part_group');
     var v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, 'f', func,func_grp_geo.x+30, func_grp_geo.y+40, 160,40,'functional_group' );
          graph.getModel().endUpdate();*/
         
      }
      
      $('#genxml').on('click', function(){
         downloadXML();  
       });
       
       main(document.getElementById('graphContainer'))
  
    
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.